# Questions about the eclipse installation genymotion plug-ins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, genymotion

Eclipse genymotion plug-in installation, enter your location in the install new software link without any reaction.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deselect the 'Group items by category' check box near the bottom of the dialog.